# Dart's equivalent to JavaScript && with potential null values

Tags: dart

There is a common JavaScript idiom (also used in few other languages) to use an alternative value in case something is null.

```
return theValue || "don't know";
```

Dart has a type-safe alternative to this which does not rely on implicit truthy/falsy conversions and does the same thing in 80 to 90% of the cases:

```
return theValue ?? "don't know";
```

Or similarly JavaScript:

```
myValue = myValue || "don't know";
```

In Dart:

```
myValue ??= "don't know";
```

JavaScript also has a similar idiom for conditionally doing something with a potentially `null` value:

```
return theValue && theValue.shoeSize;
```

Dart's type-safe alternative:

```
return theValue?.shoeSize
```

But there is a very common case that is not covered in Dart:

```
return theValue && getShoeSize(theValue);
```

In Dart:

```
return theValue == null ? null : getShoeSize(theValue);
```

Thinking about it, if Dart would have such an operator it would probably go like:

```
return theValue ?& getShoeSize(theValue);
```

Or something similar. Since nothing remotely like that appears in the docs, I assume the standard ternary with the explicit `? null :` is the best thing Dart programmers do?